# SQL select query with special modifications

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem and I don't know if there are any ways to solve it with only help of SQL.
I have a table `users`

```
+----+------------+
| ID |  group_id  |
+----+------------+
| 1  |   1;2;3    |
+----+------------+  
| 2  |  1;2;3;4   |
+-----------------+
| 3  |  1;2;3;6   |
+-----------------+
| 4  |   1;2;6    |
+-----------------+
```

I know that it's not in normal form, but I can't change it, because it's already in use by clients.

So the problem is not show users which has groups that I don't have.

For example: If I make select for user with ID = 3. I need to show user 1, 3 and 4, because user ID = 3 has all groups that has user ID = 1, but I shouldn't show user ID = 2.

**My colleague help me to find best solution, if anyone is interested:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE CONCAT('[',REPLACE('1;2;3;6', ';', ']['), ']') LIKE CONCAT('%[', REPLACE(group_id,';',']%['),']%')
```

Comment: Would be better to tell the clients there will be a change of the DB structure in the next release.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible. The whole structure should be changed, because it's all like this, and client will definitely say no.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE
INSTR(
    (SELECT group_id
    FROM users u2
    WHERE u2.id = '3'),
u.group_id) <> 0
```

Show [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97acff/4/0)

** EDIT: **

You must implement a STORED PROCEDURE for each row transform your group id string in rows of a new temporary table. So you have a situation like this:

TEMP_TABLE (user_id, group_id)

```
user_id  group_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
2          3
2          4
```

and so on

So your query can be rewrite with a NOT EXISTS condition in this way: (I've created app table but you must change my app table with an output of stored procedure)

```
create table user (id int, group_id varchar(20));
insert into user values(1, '1;2;3'),
(2, '1;2;3;4'),
(3, '1;2;3;6'),
(4, '1;2;6');

CREATE TABLE app (user_id int, group_id varchar(10));
insert into app values
(1, '1'),
(1, '2'),
(1, '3') and so on

select *
from user u
where id not in (
  select distinct a1.user_id
  from app a1
  where not exists(
    select 'x'
    from app a2
    where a2.user_id = 3
    and a2.group_id = a1.group_id
  )
)
```

Show a new [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20407/6/0)

Comment: this will also return uses who have group 13, e.g.. Not sure if this problem is relevant to the OP, though.

Comment: @Mureinik: I've fixed my query. No group 13 is different. Every group id has separated by ;

Comment: @Joe Taras - It's not so easy, I have updated my post, check it, please.

Comment: @puku: Ok, I must consider user4. Now i try and then I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: @puku: May you use temporary table together your main table users?

Comment: @JoeTaras: I think, I can use it, but I think it's not the easiest way. I think i'll better do this task with the help of php

Comment: @puku: Using of SP is adviced. It's not hard write a SP to explode the column group_id in several rows. P.S. the easyest way is restructure your table ;)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a built in command for such usecases, `find_in_set`.
Unfortunately, it only works with comma delimited values, not with values delimited by semi-colons, but that can also easily be overcome:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('3', REPLACE(group_id,';',','))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10465/5)

Comment: It's almost right, but not exactly. The problem in your variant is, for example, if I need to make a select for user ID = 1, so it should select only user with ID = 1, because other users has additional groups

Comment: That's what you requested in your OP - "show only users which has some groups or all groups that I have.". please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The right variant is: NOT show users which have groups that I don't have

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you cannot change it, but one easy solution for these cases are the Bitwise:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

eg:

I set a number scheme for the status such as:
1 = Prospective Customer
2 = Cancelled Service
4 = Pool Service
8 = lawn mowing
16 = window washing
32 = tree trimming
64 = house painting
128 = mobile oil change

With this scheme a customer who needs pool service (4) and window washing (16) will have a status of 20 (4 + 16). A prospect (1) who might be interested in a mobile oil change (128) would have a status of 129 (1+128). etc...

Bitwise logic allows me to select customers who buy particular services based on their status value.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status & 1
//returns all prospects)

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status & 16
//returns all of my window washing customers even if they are cancelled

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (status & 16) AND !(status & 2)
//returns all of my window washing customers but not the cancelled ones

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status & 36
//returns all of my tree trimming AND pool service customers i.e. 32+4

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE status & 10
//returns all cancelled lawn moving customers i.e. 2+8

SELECT * FROM customers WHERE (status & 32) AND !(status & 128)
//returns all tree trimming customers who do not get a mobile oil change
```

Comment: Table with users very large, table with groups even large, so I don't think the best way is to update users(If I understand you right, you want to add new column where I should store status).

Comment: It's more a suggestion: for each group, create a field to save a byte number (1, 2, 4, 8 ..).  Sum all "byte numbers" and save the result into the field `group_id` (instead of separated by ;) and use the selects above to retrieve the combinations as you wish.

Comment: the problem is that not only I use this table, and If I will change something it can bring a lot of problems.

Comment: Yes.  The idea was giving a different perspective for you problem and maybe you can think about it in the future ;-)

Comment: I think about it every day:) But, unfortunately, I can't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I've created "one liner" maybe it's a little bit complicated, but as plus there's no need to use stored procedure or temporary table.

Minus is a part with `select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union...` because we need to create as many rows as possible groups for one person.

Last `where id1 = 3` is your parameter.

```
create table users (id integer, group_id varchar(100));


insert into users
select 1, '1;2;3' union
select 2, '1;2;3;4' union
select 3, '1;2;3;6' union
select 4, '1;2;6';


select id2 as user_id
from (
    select u1.id as id1, u2.id as id2, count(*) as qty
    from (
        select distinct id, group_id, substring_index(substring_index(group_id, ';', t.n), ';', -1) as g_id
        from users
        cross join (
            select @i := @i + 1 as n from (select @i:=0) t0,
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1,
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
        ) as t
    ) as u1
    join users u2 on find_in_set(u1.g_id, replace(u2.group_id, ';', ',')) > 0
    group by u1.id, u2.id
) as t

join (
    select id, group_id, length(group_id) - length(replace(group_id, ';', '')) + 1 as groups_count
    from users
) as g on t.id2 = g.id and g.groups_count <= t.qty
where id1 = 3;
```

[Live example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed87e/1).

If you need more than 100 groups (per person) add another line (with different alias):

```
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) txxxx
```

I've checked it and it seams ok:

- for 1 returns 1
- for 2 returns 1, 2
- for 3 returns 1, 3, 4
- for 4 returns 4